# How to write an aspect to cater to different objects and method arguments

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am looking to write an Aspect which can be used to mock data depending on some value passed in the method. This mock will replace the actual REST call. If the value doesn't match, go back to the actual method and make the call to the REST endpoint.

I already have an aspect written that works in production but is very messy and had to implement multiple different methods in there to accommodate the need to return different objects and handle different method arguments. Is there a way I could generalise this so that I could have like a single method to perform the work and able to use if for future cases where I do not have to worry about object types and method signatures.

Current implementation as follows. How could I amend this to work as a single method which can cater to future methods and response types without having to change my Aspect?

To clarify I have the following 3 methods which I want to mock by using Aspect. as you can see I have a custom annotation that takes in a name. None of the method's arguments line up.

```
@MyMock(name = "ABC")
public AResponse getAResponse(ARequest aRequest){
    // make a REST call
}

@MyMock(name = "DEF")
public BResponse getBResponse(String fruit, BRequest bRequest){
    // make a REST call
}

@MyMock(name = "GHJ")
public CResponse getCResponse(String vehicle, CRequest cRequest, int id){
    // make a REST call
}
```

The Aspect Class currently is as follows. I use the name value in the annotation to determine which method to call and which value type to return. As you can see this is not very scalable. I need to write a new method and logic every single time I implement new mocks.

```
@Around("@annotation(myMock)")
public Object getMockedData(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, MyMock myMock) throws Throwable {
    String servName = performMocking.name();
    Object[] methodArguments = pjp.getArgs();
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
    Class returnType = signature.getReturnType();

    switch (myMock.name()) {
        case "ABC":
        getA(methodArguments[0]);
        break;
        case "DEF":
        getB(methodArguments[0]);
        break;
        case "GHJ":
        getC(methodArguments[2]);
        break;
    }
    return pjp.proceed(methodArguments);
}

private AResponse getA(ARequest aRequest){
     // I use methodArguments[0] (which is aRequest) to decide what value to return as a mock response here.
     // There is a getName value in that object which I use to reference  
}

private BResponse getB(BRequest bRequest){
     // I use methodArguments[0] (which is a String) to decide what value to return as a mock response here. 
}

private CResponse getC(CRequest cRequest){
     // I use methodArguments[2] (which is an int) to decide what value to return as a mock response here. 
}
```

All the above get methods makes a call to an external JSON file to fetch the mock data. The files content as follows. If the keys match, a mock response would be given else go back to making actual REST call.

```
{
    "ABC": {
        "enabled": "true",
        "responses": [
            {
                "a_name": "{some valid json response matching the AResponse Object structure}"
            }
        ]
    },
    "DEF": {
        "enabled": "true",
        "responses": [
            {
                "d_name": "{some valid json response matching the BResponse Object structure}"
            }
        ]
    },
    "GHJ": {
        "enabled": "true",
        "responses": [
            {
                "123": "{some valid json response matching the CResponse Object structure}"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

EDIT: Added my ASPECT class as follows:

```
package com.company.a.b.mock;

import com.domain.abc.b.logging.util.MyLogger;
import com.domain.abc.a.util.generic.ConfigHelper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Aspect
@Component
public class AspectMocking {

    private final ConfigHelper configHelper;
    private final MyLogger myLogger;

    public AspectMocking(ConfigHelper configHelper, MyLogger myLogger) {
        this.configHelper = configHelper;
        this.myLogger = myLogger;
    }

    @Around("@annotation(myMock)")
    public Object getMockedData(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, MyMock myMock) throws Throwable {

        final String env = System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
        String response = null;
        Object returnObject = null;
        String logMessage = null;
        String servName = myMock.name();
        Object[] methodArguments = pjp.getArgs();
        try {
            if ("test_env1".equals(env) || "test_env2".equals(env)) {

                MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
                Class returnType = signature.getReturnType();

                Map allDataFromMockedFile = getMockedDataFromFile();
                Map getResultForKey = (Map) allDataFromMockedFile.get(myMock.name());

                List result = null;
                if(getResultForKey != null){
                    result  = (List) getResultForKey.get("responses");
                }

                switch (myMock.name()) {
                case "ABC":
                    response = fetchABCMockedData(result, (String) methodArguments[0]);
                    logMessage = "Fetching ABC mock data for ABC Response: " + response;
                    break;
                case "V2_ABC":
                    response = fetchABCMockedData(getIntlResult(myMock.name(), (String)methodArguments[2]), (String) methodArguments[0]);
                    logMessage = "Fetching V2 ABC mock data for V2 ABC Response: " + response;
                    break;
                case "DEF":
                    response = fetchDEFMockedData(result, (String) methodArguments[0]);
                    logMessage = "Fetching DEF mock data: " + response;
                    break;
                case "GHJ":
                    response = fetchGHJMockedOfferData(result, (String) methodArguments[0], (String) methodArguments[1], (String) methodArguments[2]);
                    logMessage = "Fetching GHJ mock data: " + response;
                    break;
                }

                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
                returnObject = mapper.readValue(response, returnType);
            }
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            myLogger.addMessageAsWarning(String
                    .format("Exception occured for service %s while loading the mocked json, so hitting the actual service:"
                            + exp.getMessage(), servName));
        }

        if (returnObject == null) {
            returnObject = pjp.proceed(methodArguments);
        }

        myLogger.addMessage(logMessage);
        return returnObject;
    }


    private List getIntlResult(String name, String locale){
        Map localBasedMockFile = getMockedDataFromFile(locale.toLowerCase());
        Map localeSpecificMockedData = (Map) localBasedMockFile.get(name);
        return (List) localeSpecificMockedData.get("responses");
    }

    // had to add this recently as we needed locale values now to go to a diff file. 
    private Map getMockedDataFromFile(String countryCode){
        final String DATA_URL = String.format("/a/b/c/%s/data.json", countryCode);
        return configHelper.getMAVDataAsObject(DATA_URL, Map.class);
    }

    private Map getMockedDataFromFile() {
        final String DATA_URL = "/a/b/c/zh/mock.json";
        return configHelper.getMAVDataAsObject(DATA_URL, Map.class);
    }

    private String fetchABCMockedData(List<Map> allResponses, String vinNumber) throws IOException {
        String response = null;
        for (Map m : allResponses) {
            String mockedVinNumber = m.keySet().toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
            if (vinNumber.equals(mockedVinNumber)) {
                response = (String) m.get(mockedVinNumber);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String fetchDEFMockedData(List<String> allResponses, String vinNumber) {
        return allResponses.contains(vinNumber) ? "true" : "false";
    }

    private String fetchGHJMockedOfferData(List<Map> allResponses, String journey, String name, String pin) {
        String response = null;
        String key = journey+"_"+name + "_" + pin;

        for (Map m : allResponses) {
            String mockedKey = m.keySet().toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");
            if (mockedKey.equals(key)) {
                response = (String) m.get(mockedKey);
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: If we disregard the fact that this would never compile because in your switch-case you need to return something in order to avoid that always `proceed()` is called later, that `getB` and `getC` have the wrong signatures (should take `String` and `int` as input) and that you need to cast `getArgs[i]`, this could kinda work. Difficult to say from pseudo code what you want to achieve. E.g. none of the 4 local variables created at the beginning of your advice are ever re-used.

Comment: The following questions remain: Why you want to have everything in one advice method in the first place? Is your goal spaghetti code? You could have one advice per method signature and make it type-safe without casts. I am also wondering why you need the marker annotations because the sample method signatures have different return types. Wouldn't that be enough for the aspect to figure out which mock to return?

Answer (score 1):

Let us make your sample code compile first and then continue talking, shall we? Here is my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

**Helper classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class ARequest {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class BRequest {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class CRequest {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class AResponse {
  private String content;

  public AResponse(String content) {
    this.content = content;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "AResponse[content=" + content + "]";
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class BResponse {
  private String content;

  public BResponse(String content) {
    this.content = content;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "BResponse[content=" + content + "]";
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class CResponse {
  private String content;

  public CResponse(String content) {
    this.content = content;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "CResponse[content=" + content + "]";
  }
}
```

**Marker annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface MyMock {
  String name();
}
```

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  @MyMock(name = "ABC")
  public AResponse getAResponse(ARequest aRequest) {
    // make a REST call
    return new AResponse("real A response");
  }

  @MyMock(name = "DEF")
  public BResponse getBResponse(String fruit, BRequest bRequest) {
    // make a REST call
    return new BResponse("real B response");
  }

  @MyMock(name = "GHJ")
  public CResponse getCResponse(String vehicle, CRequest cRequest, int id) {
    // make a REST call
    return new CResponse("real C response");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application application = new Application();
    System.out.println(application.getAResponse(new ARequest()));
    System.out.println(application.getBResponse("apple", new BRequest()));
    System.out.println(application.getCResponse("bicycle", new CRequest(), 11));
  }
}
```

**Console log without aspect:**

```
AResponse[content=real A response]
BResponse[content=real B response]
CResponse[content=real C response]
```

**Aspect, variant A, using marker annotation:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.ARequest;
import de.scrum_master.app.AResponse;
import de.scrum_master.app.BResponse;
import de.scrum_master.app.CResponse;
import de.scrum_master.app.MyMock;

@Aspect
public class MockResponseAspect {
  @Around("@annotation(myMock)")
  public Object getMockedData(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, MyMock myMock) throws Throwable {
    // Whatever this does...
    //String servName = performMocking.name();
    Object[] methodArguments = pjp.getArgs();

    switch (myMock.name()) {
      case "ABC": return getA((ARequest) methodArguments[0]);
      case "DEF": return getB((String) methodArguments[0]);
      case "GHJ": return getC((int) methodArguments[2]);
      default: return pjp.proceed(methodArguments); 
    }
  }

  private AResponse getA(ARequest aRequest) {
    return new AResponse("mock A response");
  }

  private BResponse getB(String fruit) {
    return new BResponse("mock B response");
  }

  private CResponse getC(int id) {
    return new CResponse("mock C response");
  }
}
```

**Console log using aspect:**

```
AResponse[content=mock A response]
BResponse[content=mock B response]
CResponse[content=mock C response]
```

**Aspect, variant B, using return type:**

This is a simplified version of an aspect not using the mock annotation at all. Instead it could use the method name like in my example or maybe another existing method annotation like `@Response` or whatever else all response methods have in common.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;

import de.scrum_master.app.ARequest;
import de.scrum_master.app.AResponse;
import de.scrum_master.app.BResponse;
import de.scrum_master.app.CResponse;

@Aspect
public class MockResponseAspect {
  @Around("execution(* get*Response(..))")
  public Object getMockedData(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    // Whatever this does...
    //String servName = performMocking.name();
    Object[] methodArguments = pjp.getArgs();
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
    Class<?> returnType = signature.getReturnType();

    switch (returnType.getSimpleName()) {
      case "AResponse": return getA((ARequest) methodArguments[0]);
      case "BResponse": return getB((String) methodArguments[0]);
      case "CResponse": return getC((int) methodArguments[2]);
      default: return pjp.proceed(methodArguments); 
    }
  }

  private AResponse getA(ARequest aRequest) {
    return new AResponse("mock A response");
  }

  private BResponse getB(String fruit) {
    return new BResponse("mock B response");
  }

  private CResponse getC(int id) {
    return new CResponse("mock C response");
  }
}
```

The console log is the same as for the first aspect.

Now we have something to discuss. What is it you do not like about this? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for formatting. If possible, I am looking for a way to write a single class via Generics with the method getMockedData() that could handle any mock requests that come through now and in future without having to come back to this class to add new functionality every single time I need to mock something new. The marker annotation acts as the key to which json key the response would come from the file and makes it readable on what mock it points to. Writing one advice per method does sound cleaner but again means having to come back to this class every time.

Comment: I have also added My Aspect class above that compiles for reference.

Comment: Maybe it compiles for you but surely not for me because there the dependencies `MyLogger` and `ConfigHelper`) are missing. ;-) BTW, what I did was not "formatting" but programming. I created a running example.

Comment: How would generics help you here? And what would a generic aspect look like if the types and positions of parameters you need to create the mock are different for all kinds of classes and methods? If you want something generic, first you need to explain to me what all those generic cases have in common. Then maybe I can tell you how to streamline your code. It looks pretty contrived now. To me it feels like the aspect and especially the advice is doing too much (violating the single responsibility principle) and ought to be refactored into smaller, easier to read pieces.

Comment: One more remark: I am not sure I like the idea of putting annotations into your production code which serve the sole purpose of mock testing that code. And you still did not explain why you cannot just map the response type to a name/key in your JSON file. Maybe I am not seeing the full picture here. I suggest you post a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) incl. Maven build on GitHub and I can play with it.

Comment: Added a compilable Maven project here and added comments to explain issues in there. https://github.com/ambersleek/demoapp

Comment: I can run your example but I do not understand the problem. Furthermore, you commented in your code that you made `SomeRequest` package-private, which is not true. It is public and if I do make it package-private the project does not even compile anymore. So your MCVE does not really reflect the problem description. To me it seems like your problem is not related to aspects at all but rather to application design and architecture. If I could understand your problem description I might be able to help, but I don't.

Comment: Another thing is that your aspect intercepts a method with `SomeRequest` argument, i.e. the class **must** be known in that module, otherwise your sample application would not work. But if the class is known, you can also use the class and get the locale from it. Please update your MCVE to actually reflect your problem. Your code is quite contrived and your seem quite comments illogical to me.